# Sales Cloud or Service Cloud

Tags: service, sales

This may be a very basic question but once I login to an org how do I determine if it's on Sales or Service Cloud?

Items checked - In Company Information , Service Cloud licenses are there .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Typical CRM consists of 3 Sub Modules:

- Marketing (Lead, Campaign, Account and Contact Management)
- Sales (Account, Contact and Opportunity Management)
- Services (Account, Contact, Cases and Solutions Management)

**"Sales Cloud"** refers to the "sales" module in salesforce.com. It includes Leads, Accounts, Contacts, Contracts, Opportunities, Products, Pricebooks, Quotes, and Campaigns (limits apply). It includes features such as Web-to-lead to support online lead capture, with auto-response rules. It is designed to be a start-to-end setup for the entire sales process; you use this to help generate revenue.

**"Service Cloud"** refers to the "service" (as in "customer service") module in salesforce.com. It includes Accounts, Contacts, Cases, and Solutions. It also encompasses features such as the Public Knowledge Base, Web-to-case, Call Center, and the Self-Service Portal, as well as customer service automation (e.g. escalation rules, assignment rules). It is designed to allow you to support past, current, and future clients' requests for assistance with a product, service, billing, etcetra; you use this to help make people happy.

The differences between Sales Cloud and Service Cloud are the same across each "edition" ("professional", "enterprise" and "unlimited"), mainly outlined above. The differences.

As you can gather from the prior paragraphs, is that each cloud is designed to support a specific set of features that you would use to sell services and products, and support those services and products (respectively).

Comment: Thank you . So if I see that the app selected is Sales , I can safely conclude that it's on Sales Cloud?

Comment: that is correct and if you select call center it means you have selected Service cloud

Comment: And if Sales is not selected , it should be Service Cloud right ? [Account and Cases are being used ]

Comment: that is correct.